# Get all values for elements in a div

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a for loop in and it generation id for div

i need to get all values for elements in a div when click any element at div

```
<div id="{{ item3.id }}" (click)="getChildren($event)">
<input type="checkbox" name="status" [checked]="item3.templatesFields.status"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="inMain" [checked]="item3.templatesFields.inMain" />
</div>
```

and this ts code

```
public getChildren(e) {
}
```

Comment: probably want to do something with jquery. select all children and loop over them. get the input value with `.val()`

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
getChildren(e)
{
  if (e.target.children.length!=0) {
    var g=Array.from(e.target.children).forEach(y=>console.log(y.value))
     console.log(g);//here your values
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`<div id="{{ item3.id }}" (click)="getChildren(ch1, ch2)">
<input type="checkbox" name="status" #ch1 [checked]="item3.templatesFields.status"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="inMain" #ch2 [checked]="item3.templatesFields.inMain" />
</div>`

via TS you will see the `nativeElement` of both your checkboxes

```
getChildren(ch1: any, ch2: any){
  console.log(ch1);
  console.log(ch2);
}
```